# Jquery Event on Time Input

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to fire a event when i change the time in my input type time.

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-inline justify-content-center" id="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="">

      <td><label for="start">Start</label></td>

      <td><label for="end">Slut</label></td>
      <td><label for="endDuration">Tot. Tid</label></td>

      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td><input type="time" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="start" name="start" aria-describedby="startHelp" placeholder="Start"></td>

      <td><input type="time" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="end" name="end" aria-describedby="endHelp" placeholder="Slut"></td>
      <td><input type="time" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="duration" name="duration" aria-describedby="endDuration" placeholder="Tot. Tid"></td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$('#start, #end').one('keyup, change', function() {
  console.log($(this))
  var start = $('#start').val();
  console.log(start)
  var end = $('#end').val();
});
```

My problem is that the function only runs if i change both Hour AND minutes.. not if i change Hour only..

**JSFIDDLE**
https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/20350/

Comment: `one` is incorrect. Try `on`

Comment: @Saeed.Ataee Actually you can use .one read up on it on jquery.com

Comment: So separate that event handler to `$('#start')` and `$('#end')`

Comment: Interesting... :D. I will

Comment: @Saeed.Ataee Just, no. Combining selectors is absolutely fine.

Comment: Multiple event names are to be listed space-separated, not with a comma.

Comment: @CBroe strange. Change the comma for a space in the fiddle and it stop work. comma works just fine for me. The problem is the change of keyup in the time input..

Comment: No, the problem is that you are using `.one`, which has the explicit purpose of only reacting _one time_. Do you really want to react only on the first key press that happens, and ignore all others …? No, I think you rather want https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/20355/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if i change the comma for space, the event wont fire at all. Comma works fine for me. But, i'd like to fire the event even if hour isn't filled in.. is that not possible?

Comment: @BjörnC The event does fire, but unless both the hours and minutes are filled in, the overall value of the field is an empty string.

Comment: @CBroe i tried .one to see if there was any change. I normaly use .on When i use .on the event will send a function, but if i enter just minutes.. why is the value empty then?

Comment: @DarthJDG So, how can i get a value when only filling in the minutes?

Comment: Sorry, i thought you all was talking about the comma in the selector, because that was up in the first comments :)

Comment: @BjörnC I don't think you can get an incomplete value, as the browser makes sure it always returns an empty string or a valid time value. Maybe someone else knows a way. Alternatively you could default it to `00:00` or look at a third party time picker solution.

Comment: _“but if i enter just minutes.. why is the value empty then?”_ - because that is _specified_ in HTML5 for `input type=time`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this question was:

Change `.one` to `.on`
In the HTML set default input `value="00:00:00"`

Credit for comments.